# MySQL - How to set auto_increment_increment permanently, to last server restart?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to set MySQL auto_increment_increment so that it survives the server restart?

Currently I'm setting it like this:

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=2;
```

But it loses the value when I:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

And returns to default value of 1.

I'm on a AWS and I would like to be able to handle possible doomsday errors as easy as possible: by setting up a new instance from an AMI. I would like it to be ready to serve right away when it's up and avoid things like setting the auto_increment_increment -value by hand.

Comment: Permanent changes are set in configuration files. Does AWS mean you don't have direct access to the machine?

Comment: AWS stands for Amazon Web Services. We do have access to the machines and configs, so it is not an issue. I just couldn't find anything about this in the docs, hence the question.

Comment: The search feature in the on-line manual has always been awful and it got worse when Oracle purchased MySQL so I always use regular search engines. I searched for `mysql 5.7 configuration` and got [6.1.2 Server Configuration Defaults](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html) as first result. Once there it's easy to browse into the information you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set it in my.ini or my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
auto_increment_increment = 2
```

Comment: It seems to working. I couldn't find it in the docs so I wasn't sure it was possible. I'm a lot smarter now! Thanks bro!

Comment: Hmm. It seems that the auto_increment_increment is not set as yes for "Option File" in that table?... So how come it works?

Comment: It seems that the dognose removed his comment for some reason. For others to wonder, he pointed me to this table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html
with a note that Everyting that has yes in the "Option File" can be modified from the my.cnf.

Comment: Yeah, i removed it because "auto_increment_increment" does not have the "Option File" Column set to Yes. (I think this relates to the "option files" you can specify at startup - not the my.cnf itself. So if there are "exclusions" for the my.cnf, this table does not show them.)

Answer (score 1):

if you wish to set it from phpmyadmin:

1. go to main page (house in the left corner)
2. click "variables" in the main menu (more in the right)
3. find "auto_increment_increment" in the search
4. click adjust
5. save it

PS: to be sure value changed restart your mysql and apache system. Personally I use Apache2 and Mysql server 8.0 in windows 10. To do so:

1. click window icon
2. search "services" (simply start typing
3. find Mysql > right click > choose "Restart"
4. repeat this for Apache

PS: do it in the same order